# how to get average of a column with its header value from a csv and print average greater than x values in python

Tags: python

I have a csv with below data, I want average of column with all its values say: A-column returns average 7.2% and B-column returns 7.6% and lastly C-column return average of 51.5%.

so I just want to print C-column value as its greater than 50% as a checkpoint.

A-column    B-column    C-column
7.297134399 7.663726807 51.53171875
7.297134399 7.663726807 51.53171875
7.297134399 7.663726807 51.53171875
7.297134399 7.663726807 51.53171875
7.28263855  7.663726807 51.53171875
7.28263855  7.663726807 51.53171875

Comment: Do you know how to read your data into a pandas dataframe? If so, this is easy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: break your problem into steps and then research how to do each step, then you can put the parts together. e.g. 1) how to read a csv file into some data structure 2) what data structure would be most suitable if you want to calculate per-column stats 3) how to iterate over your data structure and calculate per-column stats